$\sum\sqrt[5]{(\cfrac{2a}{b+c})^3}\ge3$ for $a+b+c=3$

For $a,b,c>0,\ a+b+c=3$, prove that:
$$\displaystyle\sum\sqrt[5]{\left(\cfrac{2a}{b+c}\right)^3}\ge3$$

I think it's nesbit inequality and i have tried U.C.T and pqr method like this
$$\sum\sqrt[5]{(\cfrac{2a}{b+c})^3}=\sum\sqrt[5]{(\cfrac{2a}{3-a})^3}\ge\sum\sqrt[5]{(\cfrac{3a-1}{2})^3}$$
But it doesn't reach the solution. Can anyone give me some hint, i need a simple proof?

See art of problem solving, the post by anh1110004. It follows from this inequality by oldbeginner.
